# I am using RNN with mediapipe for my project work

Tags: project, recurrent-neural-network, mediapipe

I am getting error while running the input video by terminal in linux for mediapipe handtracking.please help me.Because I am running out of time for my project.
I am using
Bazel 4.0.0
Mediapipe hand tracking
linux 18.04

error

bazel-out/host/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/protoc '--python_out=bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/python' -Iexternal/com_google_protobuf/python -Ibazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/python bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/python/google/protobuf/any.proto)
INFO: From ProtoCompile external/com_google_protobuf/python/google/protobuf/api_pb2.py:
external/com_google_protobuf/python: warning: directory does not exist.
INFO: From ProtoCompile external/com_google_protobuf/python/google/protobuf/type_pb2.py:
external/com_google_protobuf/python: warning: directory does not exist.
INFO: From ProtoCompile external/com_google_protobuf/python/google/protobuf/duration_pb2.py:
external/com_google_protobuf/python: warning: directory does not exist.
INFO: From ProtoCompile external/com_google_protobuf/python/google/protobuf/compiler/plugin_pb2.py:
external/com_google_protobuf/python: warning: directory does not exist.
INFO: From ProtoCompile external/com_google_protobuf/python/google/protobuf/descriptor_pb2.py:
external/com_google_protobuf/python: warning: directory does not exist.
INFO: From ProtoCompile external/com_google_protobuf/python/google/protobuf/struct_pb2.py:
external/com_google_protobuf/python: warning: directory does not exist.
INFO: From ProtoCompile external/com_google_protobuf/python/google/protobuf/field_mask_pb2.py:
external/com_google_protobuf/python: warning: directory does not exist.
INFO: From ProtoCompile external/com_google_protobuf/python/google/protobuf/timestamp_pb2.py:
external/com_google_protobuf/python: warning: directory does not exist.
INFO: From ProtoCompile external/com_google_protobuf/python/google/protobuf/any_pb2.py:
external/com_google_protobuf/python: warning: directory does not exist.

mediapipe/mediapipe/calculators/tensor/BUILD:594:11: Compiling mediapipe/calculators/tensor/image_to_tensor_converter_opencv.cc failed: (Exit 1): gcc failed: error executing command /usr/bin/gcc -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -fstack-protector -Wall -Wunused-but-set-parameter -Wno-free-nonheap-object -fno-omit-frame-pointer -g0 -O2 '-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1' -DNDEBUG -ffunction-sections ... (remaining 61 argument(s) skipped)

Use --sandbox_debug to see verbose messages from the sandbox gcc failed: error executing command /usr/bin/gcc -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -fstack-protector -Wall -Wunused-but-set-parameter -Wno-free-nonheap-object -fno-omit-frame-pointer -g0 -O2 '-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1' -DNDEBUG -ffunction-sections ... (remaining 61 argument(s) skipped)

Use --sandbox_debug to see verbose messages from the sandbox
mediapipe/calculators/tensor/image_to_tensor_converter_opencv.cc: In member function 'virtual absl::lts_2020_09_23::StatusOrmediapipe::Tensor mediapipe::{anonymous}::OpenCvProcessor::Convert(const mediapipe::Image&, const mediapipe::RotatedRect&, const mediapipe::Size&, float, float)':
mediapipe/calculators/tensor/image_to_tensor_converter_opencv.cc:106:12: error: could not convert 'tensor' from 'mediapipe::Tensor' to 'absl::lts_2020_09_23::StatusOrmediapipe::Tensor'
return tensor;
^~~~~~

Answer (score 0):

It's about your compiler version. upgrade your gcc version to 8 or upper. It will work.